# What is the the fundamental group of $ H_{\mathbb{R}}/H_{\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Consider $M = H_{\mathbb{R}}/H_{\mathbb{Z}}$, where $H_{\mathbb{R}} = \lbrace\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & x & z \\
      0 & 1 & y \\
      0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}|x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$
and $H_{\mathbb{Z}} = \lbrace\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & x & z \\
      0 & 1 & y \\
      0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}|x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}\rbrace$

If we regards $M$ as a manifold (Only need to consider $M$ as topological manifold).

What is the fundamental group of $M$, $\pi_1(M)$? How to deduce that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm curious: did you lose interest in the question, are you not satisfied with the answer or what else is going on?

Comment: Sorry~ because there something bother me which makes me forget to login the forum so many days. I really appreciate your help and your answer, and I can understand your answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a group $G$ acts properly discontinuously and freely on a simply connected manifold $M$ then $\pi_1(M/G) \cong G$. Apply this to the present situation with $M = H_\mathbb{R}$ (note that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$) and $G = H_\mathbb{Z}$ to see that $\pi_1(H_\mathbb{R}/ H_\mathbb{Z}) \cong H_\mathbb{Z}$ — Note that a discrete subgroup of a Lie group always acts properly discontinuously on the surrounding Lie group.

For a proof of this, see e.g. Corollary 4.11 on page 44 [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/421/421S4_0809.pdf). You should be able to find this result or closely related ones in any decent book on algebraic or differential topology.